# When are extensions of the polynomials with coefficients in the rationals isomorphic?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

When is $\mathbb{Q}[x]/f(x) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/g(x)$, if $f(x),g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$ are polynomials of degree 2?

My initial approach to this question was to note that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/f(x) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/g(x)$ iff $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{b})$ for roots $\sqrt{a}$ of $f(x)$ and $\sqrt{b}$ of $g(x)$, but I'm unsure if this is actually a fruitful approach.

Answer (score 0):

The isomorphism class is determined by the discriminant of $f(x)$, in case of degree 2. If $f(x)=x^{2} + ax + b$ and $g(x) = x^{2} + cx + d$ are both irreducible, then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x)) \simeq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a^{2}- 4b})$, and two fields are isomorphic if and only if $(a^{2} - 4b)/(c^{2} - 4d)$ is a square of some rational number. 
If part is not hard to show, and only if part is basically same as the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ are not isomorphic as fields.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on proving the if and only if statement? I'm having trouble in the if direction, and I'm not sure what you mean in the only if direction.